# "と" plus a clause -- but what is it doing?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles

I have a question about a passage in an article I'm reading. For context, here's the passage:

> 仕事はご縁。もちろん求められていることができる能力がなければ元も子もないが、そこさえクリアしていれば、あとは相性だったりタイミングだったりする。そんなご縁が転がっているかもしれないと、筆者が時折覗いている求人サイトが「日本仕事百貨」だ。

The passage I'm interested in is this bit (specifically the part in bold):

> **そんなご縁が転がっているかもしれないと**、筆者が時折覗いている求人サイトが「日本仕事百貨」だ

I understand the meaning of the entire passage above, but I have a small grammar question about the bold part.

What is the function of the particle と in the above bold bit? I assumed initially that it functions to put the bold bit in quotes, so to speak, so as to qualify the part that comes after. But now after looking at it more closely, I think I've just confused myself.

So... what exactly is と doing in the above part? And how does the bold bit function in the whole sentence? An example translation would be great if you can offer it, so I can compare it to how I initially translated it.

手伝ってくれてありがとうございます！

Comment: This と has been discussed multiple times: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=quotative+%E3%81%A8%E8%80%83%E3%81%88%E3%80%80%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6